# Xcode Does Not Slice .ice File

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6, ice

I'm new to ICE Touch (and ICE, and Xcode), and I'm trying to use ICE Touch for my iOS app. I downloaded the IceTouch-1.3.0 and am trying to build the demo app "chat". Xcode tells me that it cannot find ChatSession.h. I find a ChatSession.ice in the file, so I'm pretty sure that it is the problem that Xcode did not slice the .ice file into ObjC files. I cannot find any helpful information on the Internet. Please help me! Thanks!!

I'm using Xcode 4.6.

---

Here's what Xcode tells me:

```
'ChatSession.h' file not found
warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/Classes/ChatSession.ice' of type text for architecture i386
warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/Classes/Chat.ice' of type text for architecture i386
```